# How to check if an Azure VM is running at a specific time via some kind of alert?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I would like to know how to create an alert for an Azure VM which tells me if the server(s) is running at a specific time.

The scenario:
Servers for the Azure network need to start at 7:30am to be ready for the users as they shut down at 7:30pm each day to save $$.
Today the azure automation script could not find any vms for the resource group! So that meant the servers where not started. I want to create an alert that will only tell me if the server(s) are not running at say 7:45am. So I can start them. 
*(Running the script now does find all of the servers now but didn't before for some reason... maybe Azure was moving the vms in the resource group?)*

I have looked at:
- Microsoft Operations Management Suit > Log Search > Add Alert Rule.
- Resource Manager > Virtual Machines > Monitoring > Alert Rules > Add metic alert & Add activity log alert.
But I can't see where to only run the alert at a specific time.

**Update/Edit:**
Script used:

```
param ( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]  
    [String]$AzureCredentialAssetName = 'AzureCred', 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]  
    [String]$AzureSubscriptionIDAssetName = 'AzureSubscriptionId'
) 

# Setting error and warning action preferences 
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" 
$WarningPreference = "SilentlyContinue" 

# Connecting to Azure 
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $AzureCredentialAssetName -ErrorAction Stop 
$null = Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable err 
$null = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable err 

# Selecting the subscription to work against 
$SubID = Get-AutomationVariable -Name $AzureSubscriptionIDAssetName 
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubID 

# Getting all resource groups 
$ResourceGroup = "Servers"

# Getting all virtual machines 
$RmVMs = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ErrorAction $ErrorActionPreference -WarningAction $WarningPreference).Name 

# Managing virtual machines deployed with the Resource Manager deployment model
"Loop through all VMs in resource group $ResourceGroup."
if ($RmVMs) 
{ 
    foreach ($RmVM in $RmVMs) 
    { 
        "`t$RmVM found ..." 
        $RmPState = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $RmVM -Status -ErrorAction $ErrorActionPreference -WarningAction $WarningPreference).Statuses.Code[1]
        if ($RmPState -eq 'PowerState/deallocated') 
        { 
            "`t$RmVM is starting up ..." 
            $RmSState = (Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $RmVM -ErrorAction $ErrorActionPreference -WarningAction $WarningPreference).IsSuccessStatusCode 

            if ($RmSState -eq 'True') 
            { 
                "`t$RmVM has been started." 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                "`t$RmVM failed to start." 
            } 
        }               
    } 
}     
else
{
    "No VMs for $ResourceGroup deployed with the Resource Manager deployment model."  
}
"Runbook Completed."
```

I just want a fail safe to know if the servers are not running when they should be.

Expected output:

```
Loop through all VMs in resource group Servers.

    DOMAINCONTROLLER found ...

    SQLSERVER found ...

    GATEWAY found ...

    APPLICATIONHOST found ...

Runbook Completed.
```

instead of:

```
Loop through all VMs in resource group Servers.

No VMs for Servers deployed with the Resource Manager deployment model.

Runbook Completed.
```

I.e. rerunning the same script manually gave expected results.

Comment: Or maybe its the wrong approach? Maybe I should create a runbook which looks at the specific server's health status via powershell script rather than an alert?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you could write a runbook script to start or stop your VM at specific time.

Comment: Do you check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management)?

Comment: If you're open to 3rd party services, look into CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com -- you can setup alerts based on time of day as well as status of metrics, have "maintenance periods" when no alerts will be raised, and even shutdown+startup VMs thru the tool (and get notified if those automation actions fail, which regular scripts do not do)

Comment: Hi all. I have the runbooks already setup to start and stop the vms using the scheudles. The main issue is just to check they are running when they are supposed to because of the issue I had this morning where none of the vms where found in my resource group "servers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, Azure metric alert could not send mail when your VM has been started or stopped at a specific time.

According to your description, [Start/Stop VMs during off-hours [Preview] solution in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management) is a good solution for you to save money.

The Start/Stop VMs during off-hours [Preview] solution starts and stops your Azure Resource Manager virtual machines on a user-defined schedule and provides insight into the success of the Automation jobs that start and stop your virtual machines with OMS Log Analytics.

It could send email notifications when the start and stop VM runbooks complete.

You also could use Azure automation to start or stop VM for a specific time, more information please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/automation/automation-scenario-start-stop-vm-wjson-tags.md).

Update:

Your script works for me. I check your script, `$RmVMs = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ErrorAction $ErrorActionPreference -WarningAction $WarningPreference).Name` returns null. Do you have multiple subscriptions? It seems that your subscription ID is wrong. Please ensure your subscription ID is right. You could get your subscription ID on your local PowerShell.

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription
```

Update2:

You could save your save your subscription to automation connection. You could use the script below:

```
param ( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]  
    [String]$AzureCredentialAssetName 

) 

# Authenticate to Azure with certificate
Write-Verbose "Get connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName" -Verbose
$connectionName = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $AzureCredentialAssetName
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $AzureCredentialAssetName        

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$ResourceGroup = "shui2"
.....
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah basically it is Start/Stop VMs during off-hours [Preview] but I had done it manually. I use different schedules for different days so can't use just the one schedule. I have one for each day for different stop times.

Comment: I also use the OMS Log Analytics to send an alert if a runbook fails. Just need an alert if a machine is not running when it should be.

Comment: @Dandaman Yes, your script works on my lab, I test on automation now.

Comment: Yeah but why didn't it work this morning? 
A bug or mainteannce of the vms? Something caused it not to find any vms for that resource group.

Comment: @Dandaman Do you ensure your SubscriptionId is correct. I check your script, `$RmVMs = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ErrorAction $ErrorActionPreference -WarningAction $WarningPreference).Name` returns null, please ensure your subscription id is right. You get it on your local powershell, `get-azurermsubscription`

Comment: Yeah when it ran this morning the subscription all appeared fine. But when it couldn't find the vms in the resource group it didn't appear. Its not like I changed the variables for the subscription or anything so maybe that is where bug was. The script couldn't load the subscription for some reason thus was not able to find any vms in the resource group because it didn't have access to any.

Comment: @Dandaman I don't think this is a bug, I suggest you could save your subscription ID to automation connection, you could use it directly. It works for me.

Comment: thanks for the updated post. I only have the one subscription. I updated my script like yours to use a connection rather than a variable for the subscription id and a credential of the co administrator account.

Comment: Fine. Please tell me the result.

Comment: The test found all the servers so I will run it like this from now on. 
So what is the AzureServicePrincipal vs the co admin account?

Comment: They are different questions. If my answer works, don't forget to accept it. Also, I will answer it about AzureServicePrincipal and the co admin account? Please wait for a moment.

Comment: `ServicePrincipal` When you have an app or script that needs to access resources, you can set up an identity for the app and authenticate the app with its own credentials. This identity is known as a service principal. You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal). `co admin account`. An Azure AD account that you give the co admin permission. But when you login to Azure, I suggest you could use ServicePrincipal, it does not leave your account information.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The new script failed today and only give the error "This job does not have any output." 
I figured out why.. "The job failed. The quota for the monthly total job run time has been reached for this subscription. To get more job run time you can change to a different Automation plan or wait until next month when the quota will be reset."

Comment: I did upgrade the plan... This was more a comment for other people who find this rather than for you Walter. =)